# swap partition not working on ver 13.10

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, mount, gparted, swap

It's a 3 day old install of Ubuntu 13.10

I set my partitions up correctly beforehand with Gparted(you'll have to trust me on that)
swap partition was formatted as `linux-swap` and given 6gb of space. My RAM is 6gb also.

In Gparted now my swap partition's file system is 'Unknown' and there is an exclamation mark after the '/dev/sda6'.

Immediately after installing Ubuntu, while booting, I would get the message that there was a problem with '/dev/mapper/cryptswap1' not being ready to mount or not being available. I followed [**this**](http://punygeek.blogspot.nl/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html) *very short* tutorial, essentially creating a new swap and reformatting. After this I no longer get the error message while booting, but my swap partition still doesn't appear to be working according to Gparted. Any help much appreciated.

/dev/sda5 is root
/dev/sda6 is swap
/dev/sda7 is home

Output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
/home/yerman/.Private on /home/yerman type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=cbb0ed41b9f457c5,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=9e985b7d47d6e940)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=yerman)
gvfsd-fuse on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

output of `free -h:`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5.5G       3.4G       2.1G         0B       164M       2.4G
-/+ buffers/cache:       842M       4.7G
Swap:         5.9G         0B       5.9G
```

output of `swapon -s`:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                  partition   6143996 0   -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

swapon /dev/sda6
```

Maybe this solve your problem